# Subversion Externals Follow Symlink

Tags: svn, symlink, externals

**Is there a way to use a symlink with the `svn:externals` property?**

I've a project running on my webserver (under unix) which has some folders that are actually symlink to other folders.

When I add the symlink to the repository it gets converted to a text file, when I checkout it on Windows.

For example, is it possible to point the externals to a path like this:

```
http://mysite/svn/mysymlink/whatineedtocheckout
```

instead of

```
http://mysite/svn/folder1/folder2/folder3/whatineedtocheckout
```

This is important because if it is possible to use a symlink this way, then it would be really simple for us to update the project externals (just by modifying the symlink).